# How Do I Add Variables To A ListBox Based On NumericUpDown Control?

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a random dice generator for a list box, and I have a numericUpDown control that is meant to represent how many of each type of die will be rolled. My current code is as follows:

```
RollValue = rand.Next(4) + 1
lstRoller.Items.Add(numD4UpDown.Value.ToString() & "D4 - " & RollValue.ToString())
```

Where lstRoller is the list box I want to add dice to, Roll Value is my variable, and numD4UpDown is my NumericUpDown. This works fine for a single die roll, but I want to be able to add an additional die roll for each number above 1 in my updown control without having to write an if statement for each numericUpDown control possibility.

Ideally it would look something like this:

```
RollValue = rand.Next(4) + 1
lstRoller.Items.Add(numD4UpDown.Value.ToString() & "D4 - " & RollValue.ToString() & If numD4UpDown.Value(Pseudocode past this point).Count > 1 then do create variable = rand.Next(4) + 1 loop until NumberOfVariables = numD4UpDown.Value.Count)
```

Is there any way of doing where I don't have to create individual If Statements?

Comment: Not sure what you are struggling to ask, but you could create a `List(Of String)` and and remove items from that and use it as a DataSource

Comment: I am bit confused myself - is `numD4UpDown` the number of dice you are rolling? And `lstRoller` is simply the display of the output of each roll? So, if you have `numD4UpDown` of 3, you will have 3 entries in `lstRoller` each with the result of an individual roll?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. numD4UpDown is just the number of dice I want to roll, and lstRoller is just the display. I would prefer to have all of the rolls on the same line, though, hence the multiple &'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> add an additional die roll for each number above 1 in my updown control

So total number of die rolls equals the number in the NumericUpDown basically.

With a For loop

```
Private rand As New Random()
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i As Integer = 1 To Convert.ToInt32(numD4UpDown.Value)
        Dim rollValue = rand.Next(4) + 1
        lstRoller.Items.Add(String.Format("{0}D4 - {1}", i, rollValue))
    Next
End Sub
```

If you want to put it all on one line, you can replace the For loop with

```
lstRoller.Items.Add(
    Enumerable.Range(1, Convert.ToInt32(numD4UpDown.Value)).
    Select(
        Function(i)
            Dim RollValue = rand.Next(4) + 1
            Return String.Format("{0}D4 - {1}", i, RollValue)
        End Function).
        Aggregate(Function(s1, s2) s1 & " " & s2))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this, except keep all of the rolls on one line?

Comment: As a side note, I don't feel good about the side effects in the Select, where new rolls are generated. It would be best if you generate the rolls separately and store them, then the select would just retrieve them. I don't have a big enough window into your code to advise how you would do that exactly.